# Glimpse showing empty Execution/SQL tab when using structuremap container for asp.net mvc5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, structuremap, glimpse

I am trying to integrate Glimpse into my asp.net mvc-5 application. I'm using structuremap to inject constructor dependencies in my `Application_Start` method.

```
_structureMapResolver = new StructureMapDependencyResolver(container);
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(_structureMapResolver);
```

I am getting empty Execution and SQL tabs. I tried commenting the above lines and loaded a regular empty constructor page, and I started getting results.

how do I get this data in this tab keeping structure map intact?
(let me know if you want the code for StructureMapDependencyResolver class.)

Thanks already.